# Why hiding login form is closing Mainform unexxpectedly?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, runtime-error

I have **two forms** in my application. When user opens up application, **login Form** appears where user enters login information and after he enters correct information, the login form should disappear and the **Main Form** must appear. The logic i am using to show Main form is:

```
if (this.userNameFld.Equals(this.userName) && this.pwdFld.Equals(this.pwd))
{
    MainForm domain = new MainForm();
    domain.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

**PROBLEM**
The problem i am facing is that as the Login form disappears, suddenly the Main form appears and gets vanished at once. And for what reason its happening, i don't know. Please help me find one. Moreover, I don't have any FormClosing event in my Login form. So what could be the bug?

Comment: Looking at this code, there does not seem to be any issue. Is there  anything that follows in Login form that closes the login form? Is there anything in MainForm load that can close it? Use ShowDialog if there is anything in LoginForm that can close it.

Comment: Let me check and then i get back Sir and would tell you about it.

Comment: This code is correct is there any other code that causes the close of MainForm?? you should show more code

Comment: Well befoe i must say something. I don't know why should somebody vote down an answered question. I mean what's wrong with this question.

Comment: I solved it everybody. Thanks everyone. See my updated answer.

Comment: You should add your answer as an answer below not an edit to the question and accept it in two days so that everyone knows it's been solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Hide();
```

is perhaps what is closing - remove `this.Hide();` and try again

Comment: Pardon Sir but i don't reckon that you have enough acquaintance with the language syntax or semantics.

Comment: LOL... ok... did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this you need to call the Main form from the main application thread instead of inside of the  login form.

One option to do this is to run the application from a standard class (not a form) that calls the login form and then have some logic that creates the main form.

Another way is to create the Main form first but call the login form from the Main form before it is visible.

```
Form frmMain = new frmMain();
```

Then inside of frmMain , instantiate the login form

Comment: Because there is no need of doing this. Check my reply. This is just to show how this could be done. It may or may not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Hide();
StuRec_frm domain = new StuRec_frm();
domain.ShowDialog();
```

This solved my problem. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score -1):

This code is just to demonstrate login and subsequent form usage(read comment to scott_f's response). Not really a response to actual question.

```
      // Assuming correct login


        // This will close the main form
        //MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
        //mainForm.Show();
        //Hide();

        // After some more code

        //Close();

        // this will not close the main form as control execution will not move ahead until Main form is closed
        MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
        Hide();  
        mainForm.ShowDialog();
        Close();
```